# What does it mean to prove $(P \to Q \to R) \to (P\to Q) \to P \to R$

Tags: logic

I'm reading [this PDF](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs430/sectionNotes/section1/CoqTutorial.pdf) in which it proves

$(P \to Q \to R) \to (P\to Q) \to P \to R$

using the Coq proof assistant.

However I'm a bit lost about what does this theorem means in terms of logic. I'm used to proofs of the type

$p\to q \iff p ∧ q$

and by doing a truth table.

However, such assertion makes no sense to me. For example, what does $(P\to Q) \to (Q\to R)$ could mean? IF $P$ is 'is raining' and $Q$ is 'if it rains, then the sky is blue', then what $(P\to Q)$ implying something would mean?

In order to understnd how to prove it in Coq I need to understand how the proof of that would work in math.

**UPDATE**

Also, why this is an axiom if I can prove it?

Comment: $(P\rightarrow Q)$ is itself a statement, call it $A$ and call $(Q\rightarrow R)$ a statement $B$. So $$(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow (Q\rightarrow R)\iff A\rightarrow B$$ The truth value of $A$ is false if and only if $P$ is true and $Q$ is false, similarly for $B$.

Comment: $\lambda f:P\to Q\to R.\lambda g:P\to Q.\lambda p:P.f(p)(g(p))$ You actually don't need to understand "how the proof [...] would work in math" to understand how to prove it in Coq. (For one reason, basic Coq tactics will completely solve this problem.) Indeed, a major point formal logic is to "mechanize" reasoning and proof assistants like Coq are manifestations of that. Also, understanding how to prove something in Coq is an excellent way to understand what's going on in "math" proofs. Admittedly, it certainly easier to understand Coq if you have a strong grasp of "math" proofs.

Comment: As an extension to the previous comment, since the "native" logic of Coq is constructive, typical tools, identities, and techniques of classical logic (such as truth tables) are somewhat counterproductive, particularly if you want to understand how Coq views things.

Comment: PS: If you have a proof of $p\to q\iff p\wedge q$ then you have ... an *unussual* proof system.  Implication and conjunction are *very often not* considered equivalent.

Comment: CoQ is natural deduction with a lot of baggage.  I suggest finding a reference to explain fitch style natural deduction, then come back to this pdf and it will make a lot more sense.

Comment: You need to parse the expression/proposition. $$ (P \to Q \to R) \to (P\to Q) \to P \to R$$ is ambiguous  $P\to Q \to R \equiv P\to (Q\to R)? or $\equiv (P\to Q)\to R$?, ditto for the rest of it.   The two answers presume a particular parsing, but may not represent the proposition you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it helps to add some parentheses. In particular, while a statement like $P \rightarrow Q \rightarrow R$ is typically regarded as ambiguous (is it $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$, or is it $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow R$?) the parser in Coq will in such a case always parse it as if the right operation hasd precedence. In other words, it will parse it as $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$.  Accordingly, the statement you are asking about is:

$$(P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)) \rightarrow ((P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow R))$$

and that should help you to think about it.

Now, one way to think about this statement is that it represents  kind of 'conditionalized Modus Ponens'.  That is, this statement effectively states that if $P$ is true, then we have Modus Ponens, for within the context of $P$,  we have that if we have $Q \rightarrow R$, then if we also have $Q$, then we have $R$.

This statement is one of the axioms in many axiom systems for propositional logic, and the reason is exactly as stated in the previous paragraph: it allows one to effectively apply Modus Ponens within any number of assumptions.  But you really have to study those axiom systems to really appreciate that.

Comment: Where I can study these axioms? Do yu have a PDF about propositionl logic that talks about them?

Comment: So if $P$ is true and $P\to (Q\to R)$ is true, and master implication is true, then everything is true by modus ponens? But how to show $P\to (Q\to R)$ is true? And how to show that the master implication is true? I'm confused.

Comment: Also, why this is an axiom if I can prove it?

Comment: You don't prove $P\to(Q\to R)$. You prove that *if* that is given, *then* $(P\to Q)\to (P\to R)$ will also be true.

Comment: @amWhy It's just how Coq's parser works.  If you want $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow R$, you have to use parentheses, but for $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$ you can drop the parentheses.  Don't ask my why they set things up that way; they just did. I'm not a fan either ...

Comment: Hmmm...  Interesting.  Thanks for the response!  I guess I wasn't even aware of Coq (yikes, I hope that doesn't age me too much!!).

Comment: @Bram28 You'd prefer it to associate to the left? Or that it should require parentheses? Here's what it would look like if we fully exploited a left associating convention: $P\to(Q\to R)\to (P\to Q\to (P\to R))$.

Comment: @DerekElkins I always much prefer just having all parentheses explicitly there.  I also don't like to see something like $P \land Q \rightarrow R$ even though most likely that's meant as $(P \land Q )\rightarrow R$. Small effort to avoid any ambiguities is worth it I say.

Comment: @amWhy Coq is almost 30 years old, so presumably that would age you except no one would expect that the reason you're unfamiliar with Coq was that it was too new. That said, this convention for the (right) associativity of $\to$ is very common in type theory and programming languages. It's natural when you think of $P\to Q$ as being a type of functions from (proofs of) $P$ to (proofs of) $Q$. When multiparameter functions are represented in a curried style, right associating $\to$ allows $P\to(Q\to(R\to S))$ to be $P\to Q\to R\to S$ for the currying of $P\times Q\times R\to S$.

Comment: I'm not that old, Derek!  Besides, my background didn't involve reliance on computer assisted proof assistants.  So I hardly think I'm any for the worse of not relying on Coq to tell me how to parse logic.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\fitch#1#2{~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

> So if $P$ is true and $P→(Q→R)$ is true, and master implication is true, then everything is true by modus ponens? But how to show $P→(Q→R)$ is true? And how to show that the master implication is true? I'm confused.

No, no, no.   You don't prove $P\to (Q\to R)$.   You prove that if *that* is given, then $(P\to Q)\to (P\to R)$ will *also* be true.

What the Coq app is doing is: Assume $P\to(Q\to R)$, $P\to Q$, and $P$; and use *modus ponens* to derive that $R$ will be true under those hypothesi; so you may use deduction to prove the statement is a theorem of this proof system.

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{1.~P\to (Q\to R)~:\textsf{assumption}}{\fitch{2.~P\to Q\qquad\quad:\textsf{assumption}}{\fitch{3.~P\qquad\qquad\quad:\textsf{assumption}}{4.~Q\to R\qquad~~~:\textsf{modus ponens (1,3)}\\5.~Q\qquad\qquad\quad:\textsf{modus ponens (2,3)}\\6.~R\qquad\qquad\quad:\textsf{modus ponens (4,5)}}\\7.~P\to R\qquad\quad~:\textsf{deduction (3,6)}}\\8.~(P\to Q)\to(P\to R):\textsf{deduction (2,7)}}\\9.~(P\to(Q\to R))\to((P\to Q)\to(P\to R)):\textsf{deduction (1,8)}}$$

> Also, why this is an axiom if I can prove it?

It is considered an axiom in *some* proof systems; not all.   There are many proof systems which use various axioms and rules of inference.   For instance, formal proof systems (such as used above) use very few axioms but several of rules of inference.   The statement is often *not* taken as an axiom in such a system, but is often a theorem (as for instance, we just proved it so in any formal system that accepts *modus ponens* and deduction).   However, there are other systems which have few rules of inference (often only *modus ponens*) but several axioms.   The statement is often taken as an axiom in such axiomatic proof systems.

When you have two proof systems where *either* one may prove *all* the axioms and justify *all* the rules of inference accepted in the other, then they will each be able to prove the same theorems.

---

> For example, what does $(P→Q)→(P→R)$ could mean?

- $P$: There is good rain
- $Q$: The plants will grow strong.
- $R$: We will have a good harvest.

  - $P\to(Q\to R)$ If there is good rain, then we will have a good harvest *if* the plants will grow strong.

    - Which implies $(P\to Q)\to(P\to R)$ If having good rain means the plants will grow strong, then having good rain means we will have a good harvest.

Comment: I understood everything, except why $P\to Q$ is also an assumption

Comment: Because you have a nested implication $\color{red}{(P\to (Q\to R))}\to(\color{blue}{(P\to Q)}\to(\color{green}P\to R))$.

Comment: Sorry, can't understand. Can you be more clear?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs To prove a conditional statement $\phi\to\psi$ you assume $\phi$ and make some argument to derive $\psi$ under that assumption. So to prove $\psi\to(\phi\to(\rho\to\xi)))$ you assume $\psi,\phi,\rho$ and demonstrate a derivation of $\xi$ under those assumptions, then deduce the statement by discharging the assumptions .

Comment: Ok, I revised your proof. I understand that if $P\to (Q\to R)$, $P\toQ$ and $P$ are given, then the formula can be proved as true. But what happends in the case they're not true? And why did you choose excatly them to be true?

Comment: The *conditional* statement $A\to B$ being true means that if $A$ is true then so is $B$. However, if $A$ is false, $A\to B$ does not promise anything.  So too, the *conditional* statement $(P\to (Q\to R))~\to~((P\to Q)\to (P\to R))$ being true means that if $(P\to (Q\to R))$ is true then so too  is $(P\to Q)\to (P\to R)$ .

Comment: I thought that proving such formula involved proving it's a tautology, that is, all substitutions of $P,Q,R$ will make the formula true. But it seems that what you made was assuming the formula is true and then finding which assumptions would made it actually true.

Comment: Yes. @GuelandoOCS .  For example: $(A\land B)\to A$ is a tautology.  It is true for all assignments of the literals $A, B$, including those which make $A\land B$ false.

Comment: $\begin{array}{|l}\hline\begin{array}{|l}A\land B\\\hline A\end{array}\\ (A\land B)\to A\end{array}$